# Как адптировать iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

Есть iframe qiwi копилки,но у него идет фиксированная ширина 520х260. Если изменить даже пропорционально - плывет текст. В мобильной версии отображается ужасно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://jsfiddle.net/24nz67rt/

```
<iframe src="https://qiwi.me/action/widget/test_babosiki" width="520" height="260" frameBorder="0" ref="widget"/>
```

Comment: Если страница во фрейме не поддерживает адаптивность, то вы ничего не сможете сделать. Это чужой сайт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все же пропорционально можно уменьшить/увеличить `

```
iframe {
transform: scale(0.5);
```

}

При увеличении придется поработать с позицией.

Comment: О_о , мне все твердили что сделать это невозмможно,но... Уже второй вопрос где смогли помочь только вы. Спасибо большущее)

Comment: пожалуйста, но это скорее костыль а не решение)